# Assert the text present in a disable text box using selenium webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following text field and is disabled. It will have a text value say 'City1'. I need to verify 'City1' is displayed in this text box. .getAttribute('value') and .getText is not working.

```
 <input type="text" autofocus="" disabled="disabled" ng-model="siteDetails.streetAddr" class="form-control ic-filterdropdown ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Comment: You could try .getAttribute('innerHTML'). This will get all the text inside this element. If I'm correct it'll also get the child elements etc. so it's not preferable. But since .getAttribute('value') and .getText aren't working for you I don't see another way to do this.

Comment: Come to think of it there might by a better way. Try this: .getAttribute('ng-model')

Comment: which programming language you use?

Comment: Please post the code of the test (the ones that are not working).
Also it would be great to have the output (generated) HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `yourelement.getAttribute("textContent / innerHTML / innerText /value")`.. one of this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
attribut = element.getAttribute(nom_attribut)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute